# malformedXML: During update: adminUsersForm not found

Tags: ajax, forms, jsf, rendering

I'm having some doubts about ajax on JSF.

My xhtml looks like this:

```
<h:body>
<h:form id="menuForm">
    <h:outputLabel for="menu">Available actions: </h:outputLabel>
    <h:selectOneMenu id="menu" value="#{menu.mainMenuItem}">
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select an option..." itemValue="null" />
        <f:selectItems value="#{menu.mainMenuItems}" />
        <f:ajax render=":menuForm :adminUsersForm :loadInfoForm :viewFilesForm" />
        <!-- <f:ajax render="@all" /> -->
    </h:selectOneMenu>
</h:form>

<h:form id="adminUsersForm"
    rendered="#{menu.mainMenuItem == 'Admin users.'}">
    <h:commandButton value="Button 1" />
</h:form>

<h:form id="loadInfoForm"
    rendered="#{menu.mainMenuItem == 'Load info.'}">
    <h:commandButton value="Button 2" />
</h:form>

<h:form id="viewFilesForm"
    rendered="#{menu.mainMenuItem == 'View files.'}">
    <h:commandButton value="Button 3" />
</h:form>
</h:body>
```

When I use `<f:ajax render=":menuForm :adminUsersForm :loadInfoForm :viewFilesForm" />` I get the malformedXML error, on the other hand when I use `<f:ajax render="@all" />` the correct `<h:form>`is rendering.

Whats happening in here? I read that using ajax we can render components **just** inside the same **form**, but if we use the `:componentID` it is possible to render -using ajax- components outside a form.

Thanks in advance, and maybe it's a basic question but I'm very new to JSF and trying to learn.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The `<f:ajax render>` should point to client IDs which is **always** present in the JSF-generated HTML DOM tree. This is mandatory because it's JavaScript in the client side which needs to update the HTML DOM tree. However, you're pointing it to client IDs which are *not* present in the HTML DOM tree because they are not been rendered by JSF.

You need to put those elements with a `rendered` attribute in a parent component which is **always** present in the JSF-generated HTML DOM tree.

Here is one way:

```
<h:form id="menuForm">
    <h:outputLabel for="menu">Available actions: </h:outputLabel>
    <h:selectOneMenu id="menu" value="#{menu.mainMenuItem}">
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select an option..." itemValue="null" />
        <f:selectItems value="#{menu.mainMenuItems}" />
        <f:ajax render=":menuForm :adminUsers :loadInfo :viewFiles :adminUsersForm :loadInfoForm :viewFilesForm" />
    </h:selectOneMenu>
</h:form>

<h:panelGroup id="adminUsers">
    <h:form id="adminUsersForm" rendered="#{menu.mainMenuItem == 'Admin users.'}">
        <h:commandButton value="Button 1" />
    </h:form>
</h:panelGroup>

<h:panelGroup id="loadInfo">
    <h:form id="loadInfoForm" rendered="#{menu.mainMenuItem == 'Load info.'}">
        <h:commandButton value="Button 2" />
    </h:form>
</h:panelGroup>

<h:panelGroup id="viewFiles">
    <h:form id="viewFilesForm" rendered="#{menu.mainMenuItem == 'View files.'}">
        <h:commandButton value="Button 3" />
    </h:form>
</h:panelGroup>
```

Here is another way (which I recommend more if there's actually no to-be-updated content between the forms):

```
<h:form id="menuForm">
    <h:outputLabel for="menu">Available actions: </h:outputLabel>
    <h:selectOneMenu id="menu" value="#{menu.mainMenuItem}">
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select an option..." itemValue="null" />
        <f:selectItems value="#{menu.mainMenuItems}" />
        <f:ajax render=":menuForm :otherForms :adminUsersForm :loadInfoForm :viewFilesForm" />
    </h:selectOneMenu>
</h:form>

<h:panelGroup id="otherForms">
    <h:form id="adminUsersForm" rendered="#{menu.mainMenuItem == 'Admin users.'}">
        <h:commandButton value="Button 1" />
    </h:form>

    <h:form id="loadInfoForm" rendered="#{menu.mainMenuItem == 'Load info.'}">
        <h:commandButton value="Button 2" />
    </h:form>

    <h:form id="viewFilesForm" rendered="#{menu.mainMenuItem == 'View files.'}">
        <h:commandButton value="Button 3" />
    </h:form>
</h:panelGroup>
```

Note that in the both ways I've included the IDs of all other forms in the `render` as well. This is to workaround a bug in JSF Ajax JavaScript (which is to be fixed in JSF 2.2). For a detailed explanation, see also [Ajax rendering of content which contains another form](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2011/09/communication-in-jsf-20.html#AjaxRenderingOfContentWhichContainsAnotherForm).

Comment: Ok, got it. Is there too much difference between `<f:ajax render=":menuForm :otherForms :adminUsersForm :loadInfoForm :viewFilesForm" />` and `<f:ajax render="@all" />` ?? Because the second option worked even if there was no parent component always present. Just wanna have clear concepts. THanks

Comment: The major difference is in the transferred data. If you have lot of other content outside the forms, then the `@all` would transfer unnecessary data which makes the response size bigger which thus makes it all slower. Also, the `@all` has the same problem as described in the last paragraph of the answer, you'd still need to explicitly specify the form IDs in the `render`.

Comment: @BalusC Thanks for this answer, I understood what's the problem.